# Why can I not invoke this method on an array type int[][]

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to reference a method in a class inside of another method, but it is telling me it can't be invoked on int[][], int[] or primitive int.

Different types of arrays and primitive data can't be passed through either

CLASS BACKGROUND

```
public class MultiStatsArray {

    private int rowSize;  //number of rows
    private int columnSize; //number of columns
    private int[][]stats; // an array of integers
    private int temp = 0;


    //default constructor
    //by default the array has 10 rows and 5 columns
    MultiStatsArray() {
        rowSize = 10;
        columnSize = 5;
        stats = new int[rowSize][columnSize];
    }

        public int getRowAvg(int row) {
            //computes and return the sum of a given column
        int rowTotal = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            rowTotal = rowTotal + stats[row][i];
        }

        return rowTotal/5;
         }
```

MY PROBLEM

```
public void display() {

    //displaying the array with row total at the end of the row
    for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        System.out.print(stats[n][0] + "  ");
        System.out.print(stats[n][1]+ "  ");
        System.out.print(stats[n][2]+ "  ");
        System.out.print(stats[n][3]+ "  ");
        System.out.println(stats[n][4]);
        System.out.println(stats.getRowTotal(n));
    }
}
```

I expected it to simply refer to how I asked it to process the columns and rows but it seems it isn't allowing to be invoked for a double array. I don't really understand using something.Method, I'm much more familiar with Method(something) so this might be really simple

Comment: Please define "isn't allowing to be invoked."  What actual error do you see, what do you expect to see instead.

Comment: do you have this method `getRowTotal` in your class?, call it directly `System.out.println(getRowTotal(n));`

Comment: What is your intent with `stats.getRowTotal(n)`? Where is `getRowTotal` defined?

Comment: In addition to previous comments, how to you populate stats?  It's declared private in its own class.

Comment: @WJS I think that method `display` is meant to be part of the class `MultiStatsArray` so it can access private methods.  But it's not clear from the code.

Comment: @markspace  Yes.  But I was talking about `populating` the array with values.  I guess not all the code is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have a class `MultiStatsArray` that has an `int[][]` field called `stats`, and (presumably) a method called `getRowTotal(int n)`. This method belongs to the object itself, not the `stats` field. Instead of trying to call it with `stats.getRowTotal(n)` you should simply do `getRowTotal(n)`.

Your error message is telling you precisely this. The method `getRowTotal` cannot be invoked on `stats` (which is an `int[][]`).